# I'm want to convert the difference between two dates, using DATEDIFF to an integer

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

For the Rails project I'm currently working on, I need to check if the current date has surpassed a certain time period (65% of the start date - end date period). Therefore I created this query with Active Record:

```
Mentoropleiding.joins(:sectoraal_partnerschap, mentor: [{ 
onderneming_mentoren: :onderneming}]).where(mentoropleidingen: { 
status: 3 }).where('CONVERT(int,eind_datum_opvolging) > 
(DATEDIFF(day, eind_datum_opvolging, start_datum_opvolging) * 
0.65)')
```

But if I'm running this sql, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed.)
```

So the problem is this line:

```
CONVERT(int,eind_datum_opvolging)
```

I'm trying to convert a date into an int, but this is not allowed. Does anyone know how to convert a `DATEDIFF` result to an integer?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: The result of `datediff()` is an integer.  There is no need to do a conversion.  That said, this code should not be generating that error.  I would suggest providing sample data, desired results, and examples of the code that is actually failing.

Comment: thanks Gordon, I tried to use datediff without convert, this is the full sql query:

Mentoropleiding.joins(:sectoraal_partnerschap, mentor: [{ onderneming_mentoren: :onderneming}]).wher
e(mentoropleidingen: { status: 3 }).where('eind_datum_opvolging > (DATEDIFF(day, eind_datum_opvolging, start_datum_op
volging) * 0.65)')

but when I run this I also get the error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with numeric)

Comment: The issue is not with the `DATEDIFF` but the the fact that you are comparing a date with the result of it (i.e. `eind_datum_opvolging > (DATEDIFF(day, eind_datum_opvolging, start_datum_op volging) * 0.65)`, so you are trying to work out if a date is larger than a number, hence your error

Comment: Hi Gareth, yeah I noticed that now, but I tried to convert the date to an int like this:

CONVERT(int, eind_datum_opvolging)

But then I get the error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed.)

Comment: Even if you could convert a date to an int, I don't think that is what you want in this case. Your logic refers to wanting to get current days passed the end date, but you never actually refer to the current date.... I think you want something like: `DATEDIFF(DAY, eind_datum_opvolging, GETDATE()) > 
(DATEDIFF(day, eind_datum_opvolging, start_datum_opvolging) * 
0.65)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion Gareth, and this seems to work, thanks a lot!

Comment: I just needed to replace eind_datum_opvolging with start_datum_opvolging in the first DATEDIFF clause. Now it works, thanks again Gareth!!

Comment: What logic are you actually trying to achieve here, your current code doen't really make any sense

Comment: Hi Charlieface, I need to filter the records where 65% of the time between start date and end date of a training has passed. This seems to work:

Mentoropleiding.joins(:sectoraal_partnerschap, mentor: [{ onderneming_mentoren: :onderneming}]).wher
e(mentoropleidingen: { status: 3 }).where('DATEDIFF(DAY, start_datum_opvolging, GETDATE()) >  (DATEDIFF(day, eind_dat
um_opvolging, start_datum_opvolging) *  0.65)')